# how to get value from getCurrentUserSync angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

how to get this value from Profile variable , i want to get but not success anyone know please help me this check image
when i check data console.log(this.Profile);  its show below picture data

```
 this.Profile = Auth.getCurrentUserSync();
   console.log(this.Profile.email);

     Resource {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false}
        $promise :    Promise {$$state: {…}}
        $resolved : true
        brand_id :  [{…}]
        created_date : "2017-11-18T07:29:19.012Z"
        email: "abc@gmail.com"
        name : "Sami"
       phone_no  :  "12345678"
        provider : "local"
        role :   "company_manager"
        updated_date   :  "2017-11-18T07:29:19.012Z"
        user_name :  "abc@gmail.com"
        __v : 0
     _id: "5a0fe14f183a8f1bf0762450"
        __proto__:
        Object
```

[image]

Comment: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Comment: console.log(this.Profile.email);  when i use   Undefined

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'resource' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

two questions:

is method Auth.getCurrentUserSync an async call? If yes, you can only do operation in callback function like:

```
Auth.getCurrentUserSync().then(function (response) {
    this.Profile = response;
    console.log(this.Profile.email);
})
```

What's screenshot from? Is it from console.log(this.Profile)? Maybe you can provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser;    
    this.getCurrentUser(function(data){
      console.log('email: ', data.email); 

    });
```